# extension host terminated unexpectedly on opening .php file

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code

This pops up in VSCode everytime I open a php file:

> "extension host terminated unexpectedly"

Steps that I've done:

1. I disabled all the plugins but still no light.
2. I also got the latest version of vscode.
3. Uninstalled and Reinstalled Git
4. Disabled git in settings.

This error prevents me from using html tags autocomplete

Comment: Have you tried re-installing Git? I had this problem and I tried heaps of solutions, and re-installing Git solved it for me.

Comment: @JordanQuartermain yes